# MySQL C++ Connector: SIGABRT Connecting to Database

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.10

I am having a hard time getting past this bug.  Recently, changed from VM of Ubuntu 14.04 to making Ubuntu 15.10 my host OS.  Now I am having a myriad of issues with this project; this one being the most recent.  I am getting a SIGABRT signal when executing the code that calls this function `DB_Interface::DB_Interface(int Preset)`.  When this function is called from an executable, the error arises in the second `try{}catch{}` block.  So I don't think it something specific to `SetSchema`.

I have tried reinstalling all the mysql libraries and tools([HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614551/how-to-get-mysql-server-setup-on-ubuntu-15-04)).  I have checked accessing the server from the command prompt with the same credentials with no problem.  So I am leaning to incompatibility of the C++ connector with something... The million dollar question.  So my question is how to resolve this issue.  More info below:

System Info:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27

Code Excerpt:

```
DB_Interface::DB_Interface(int Preset) {

try{
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    flags[0] = 0;
}
catch(...)
{
    flags[0] = 1;
    printf("DB_Interface: Flag 0 has been set.");
    throw Except;
}
try{
    con = driver->connect("localhost:3306", "CANS_OPERATION", "SMOOTH_OPERATOR");
    flags[1] = 0;
}
catch(...)
{
    flags[1] = 1;
    printf("DB_Interface: Flag 1 has been set.");
    throw Except;
}

try{
    con->setSchema("CANS_SQL"); //SIGABRT occurs in executing this line.
    std::string Query = "UNLOCK TABLES";
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    stmt->execute(Query);
    flags[4] = 0;
}
catch(sql::SQLException &e)
{
    flags[4] = 1;
    printf("DB_Interface: Flag 4 has been set");
    throw Except;
}
```

**EDIT 1**
The following has also been attempted with no success.

```
sudo apt-get install cpp:i386 gcc:i386 g++-5:i386 gcc-5:i386 g++:i386 libboost-dev:i386 binutils:i386
```

Followed by a reinstall of libmysqlcppconn-dev.

Comment: Do you need to specify protocol, eg `con = driver->connect("tcp://localhos...`

Comment: That'll be the first thing I try tomorrow morning, but I would be surprised since I didn't do so previously.

Comment: The same error results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that may have the same issue, this has been resolved.  When I moved to Ubuntu 15.10, I used the same schema model as I did in my last setup.  After testing on a completely separate schema for a test project, I noticed no issues.  This gave me the hunch that recreating my schema in this version of MySQL and Ubuntu may alleviate some issues.  Surprise, surprise it did.  After that I recreated the user "CANS_OPERATION".  My excerpt above then worked. To get the MATLAB wrapper to work with it as well, I changed from the recommended g++-4.7 compiler for mex functions to the most recent release.  Hope this finds someone well.